# Forbid users from executing WebApi actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following WebApi action that deletes an order from the back-end database, only for users that are in the `Admin` and `Order` roles.  However, if the user is also in the `Readonly` role the action returns a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Order")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int orderid) {
    if(User.IsInRole("Readonly")) { return Forbidden(); }

    var order = await _repository.Get(orderid);
    if(order != null) {
        await _repository.Delete(orderid);

        return NoContent();
    }
    else {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

What I'd like to know is it possible to prevent actions from being executed if users are in specific roles so that I do not have to put `if(User.IsInRole("Readonly")) { return Forbidden(); }` at the start of all database update-able action methods, e.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Order")]
[NotAuthorized(Roles = "Readonly")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int orderid) {

    var order = await _repository.Get(orderid);
    if(order != null) {
        await _repository.Delete(orderid);

        return NoContent();
    }
    else {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

The `NotAuthorized` action filter will return a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response if the user is in the `Readonly` role.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to implement a reverse of the `[Authorize()]` attribute and forbid users from executing MVC WebApi actions if they are a member of one or more roles.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace MyAPI {

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method,AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class NotAuthorizedAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            IPrincipal user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
            if(!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
            else {
                bool userInRole = false;
                foreach(var role in Roles.Split(',')) {
                    if(user.IsInRole(role)) {
                        userInRole = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(userInRole) {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this filter attribute simply decorate any actions that you don't want users to execute if they're a member of a restricted role, e.g. if the user is part of a read-only role they not permitted to update the database:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Order")]
[NotAuthorized(Roles = "Readonly")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int orderid) {
    var order = await _repository.Get(orderid);
    if(order != null) {
        await _repository.Delete(orderid);

        return NoContent();
    }
    else {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```